# undefined method `full_name' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods, status

This is an exercise on teamtreehouse.com.

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :confirmable,
  # :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me,
                  :first_name, :last_name, :profile_name

  validates :first_name, presence: true

  validates :last_name, presence: true

  validates :profile_name, presence: true,
                           uniqueness: true

  has_many :statuses

  def full_name
    first_name + " " + last_name
  end
end
```

status.rb

```
class Status < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :content, :user_id
  belongs_to :user
end
```

I'm getting the following error.

```
undefined method 'full_name' for nil:NilClass
```

Showing /app/views/statuses/index.html.erb where line #9 raised:

```
6: 
7: <% @statuses.each do |status| %>
8: <div class="status">
9:  <strong><%= status.user.full_name %></strong>
10:     <p><%= status.content %></p>
11:     <div class="meta">
12:       <%= link_to time_ago_in_words(status.created_at) + " ago", status %>
```

I would really like to understand why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that when I was building the status portion prior to the user part, I had generated test statuses that didn't have a first_name or a last_name.
 
The way to fix it was to open the rails console type: `rails console` then `Status.delete_all`

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to post this answer! Life saver!

Answer (score 4):

hello i guess  you done spelling mistake writing

```
 User.rb file in model

has_many :statuses
```

please do proper association .

it to be

```
<% statuses.user.full_name %>
```

Comment: I thought you write in plural and ruby can understand??? Also did try it just for the heck of it and it did in fact return an error for changing it to statuses.

Answer (score 1):

The error is because some records doesn't have one of the names, you can avoid the error using the following code.

```
<%= status.user.try(:full_name) %>
```

if full_name works it puts the string in the other way it puts "" or nil

Answer (score 0):

Add the attribute `full_name` in your model.

```
attr_accessible :full_name
```

Then Update the

```
 def full_name
    first_name + " " + last_name
  end
```

as follows,

```
  def full_name
    self.full_name = self.first_name + " " + self.last_name
  end
```

Comment: shouldnt it be `attr_accessor` rather then `attr_accessible`